# passing parameters to apscheduler handler function

Tags: python

I am using apscheduler and I am trying to pass in parameters to the handler function that gets called when the scheduled job is launched:

```
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
import time

def printit(sometext):
    print "this happens every 5 seconds"
    print sometext

sched = Scheduler()
sched.start()

sometext = "this is a passed message"
sched.add_cron_job(printit(sometext), second="*/5")

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Doing this gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: func must be callable
```

Is it possible to pass parameters into the function handler. If not, are there any alternatives? Basically, I need each scheduled job to return a string that I pass in when I create the schedule. Thanks!

Comment: what is `while True:
    time.sleep(1)`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`printit(sometext)` is not a callable, it is the result of the call.

You can use:

```
lambda: printit(sometext)
```

Which is a callable to be called later which will probably do what you want.

Comment: Sweet it works! Do you think you can quickly explain why this works/ how this fixes the error? Thanks!

Comment: It is explained. You need to pass a function, i.e. something that can be called. def foo(): pass   "foo" is the function "foo()" is the return value of calling that function.

Comment: @still.Learning
Python supports the creation of anonymous functions (i.e. functions that are not bound to a name) at run time, using a construct called "lambda".
This is a normal function -> def f (h): return h**10, 
and this is a lambda functin -> g = lambda h: h**10,
notice the difference 
;)

Comment: NOTE: You cannot use lambdas as the callable if you're using a persistent jobstore with apscheduler (like PostgreSQL, Redis, etc). You'll get this error: "ValueError: This Job cannot be serialized since the reference to its callable could not be determined. Consider giving a textual reference instead."

Answer (score 39):

Since this is the first result I found when having the same problem, I'm adding an updated answer:

According to the [docs](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/schedulers/base.html#apscheduler.schedulers.base.BaseScheduler.add_job) for the current apscheduler (v3.3.0) you can pass along the function arguments in the `add_job()` function.

So in the case of OP it would be:

```
sched.add_job(printit, "cron", [sometext], second="*/5")
```

Comment: If you do named arguments you should have preceded job function arguments with arg. Example: args= [arg1, arg2]

Comment: Latest link: https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/modules/schedulers/base.html#apscheduler.schedulers.base.BaseScheduler.add_job

Answer (score 2):

Like Niel mention, with the current apscheduler you can use:
**args** (list|tuple) – list of *positional arguments* to call func with. [See doc](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/modules/schedulers/base.html#apscheduler.schedulers.base.BaseScheduler.add_job) 
Example:

`sched.add_job(printit, args=[sometext], trigger='cron', minutes=2)`